# fsockopen only working to check port 80 and 8000 (no other ports)

Tags: php, port, fsockopen

I'm trying to use fsockopen as a port checker to see if a specific port is open on an IP address, but it only seems to be working on Ports 80 and 8000. For any other port, it returns that the port is closed even when it is open. I was wondering how I could possibly fix this?

```php
$server_ip= $_POST['server']; 
$port = $_POST['port'];
$server_ip = gethostbyname($server_ip);
$status = array();

if (empty($_POST["server"]) || empty($_POST['port']) || !filter_var($server_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) )
{
    echo "some html code";
}

elseif (!(is_numeric($port)))
{
    echo "some other html code";
}

else
{
    if($pf = @fsockopen($_POST['server'], $port, $err, $err_string, 1)) {
        $status = true;
        fclose($pf);
    } else {
        $status = false;
    }

Output code here..
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace and `f($pf...` if probably meant to be `if($pf...`

Comment: What other ports are you trying? PHP probably doesn't have permission to open ports outside the [registered port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port) range

Comment: @Phil Thanks, I fixed the "if" and closing brace. They were fixed in my code but when I had to get the indentation to work on stackoverflow it messed it up. So still no progress there. And yes I am pinging registered port range, 81, 82, 83, 5004, are a few examples. Any other ideas?